# Xamarin Forms - Using Async SelectedIndexChanged in picker selection

Tags: .net, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms, eventhandler

I am implementing an app in Xamarin Forms for both Android and iOS, which communicate with a WebAPI (.NET) to retrieve information from a database. 
At some point, I have a screen with several pickers. Let's say in picker1 we select a Country; aftwerwards in picker2 we select a city.

When a country is selected in picker1, it rise a SelectedIndexChanged event (called OnSelectedCountry) which calls the WebAPI to retrieve cities from that specific country, and then binds the city names to picker2 by means of picker2.ItemsSource.

This results in sloppy performance and looks like the app is stucked while executing OnSelectedCountry, because the list of countries from picker1 isn't closed until OnSelectedCountry ends. 
How could I close the list items from picker1 right after selecting a country? Or show a 'loading' image on top of it.

I already tried solutions from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30138018/xamarin-forms-using-async-to-apply-listview-itemsource) but they didn't work.

Snnipet of code (models of variables are omitted for simplicity):

**XAML**

```
<Picker x:Name="picker1" Title="Select a country" ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding name}" SelectedIndexChanged="OnSelectedCountry" IsEnabled="False"/>
<Picker x:Name="picker2" Title="Select a city" IsEnabled="False" ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding name}"/>
```

**CS**

```
 ...

 private ObservableCollection<City> _replyCities;

 ...

 async void OnSelectedCountry(object sender, EventArgs e)
 { 
      Country selectedCountry = (Country)picker1.SelectedItem;
      string decodedJson = await RestService.GetDataAsync(selectedCountry.name);
      Reply reply = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Reply>(decodedJsonInput);

      _replyCities = new ObservableCollection<City>(reply.Cities);
      picker2.ItemsSource = _replyCities;
      picker2.IsEnabled = true;
 }
```

Conection with WebAPI is performed in RestService class like:

```
public static async Task<String> GetDataAsync(string queryInput)
{ ... }
```

Comment: run it in a separate Task

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I highly suggest reading about async task as it can be a very tricky one if you're not familiar with it. You will avoid many problems in the future if you do.

This code uses different methods in place of your code as I really didn't want to write all the classes etc to test the code but hopefully the comments will help you out to integrate this into your solution.

**UPDATE**: since the below solution didn't work with Laura's method I suspected the HTTP call wasn't using await and thus wasn't async. This was the true cause for the UI getting blocked.

```
    private void Picker1_OnSelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // add code here to display wait icon if you want


        // replace with RestService.GetDataAsync
        Task.Delay(5000)
            .ContinueWith(t =>
        {
            // in the case there is an error making the REST call
            if (t.IsFaulted)
            {
                // handle error
                return;
            }

            // t.Result will have the REST response so replace this code with yours
            var cities = new ObservableCollection<string>(new[] {"1", "2"});

            // Since you're running a new task it is important to make sure all UI 
            // changes are ran in the main UI thread. This will make sure of that.
            Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
            {
                Picker2.ItemsSource = cities;
                Picker2.IsEnabled = true;
                // if you displayed wait icon make sure it is disabled here now that the function has completed

            });
        });
    }
```

```

Comment: Hi, I tried to integrate this solution but id didn't work as expected. It performs as before and the screen freezes anyway. 
I replace it as `RestService.GetDataAsync(selectedCountry.name).ContinueWith( ...`

Comment: That's odd as it worked without any screen freezing. Oh well if the other solution works for you then you can move forward. I still recommend taking a look how async task works as it will speed up your development in the future.

Comment: Are you sure that the 'RestService.GetDataAsync' implementation is asynchronous? Take a look if there is a warning CS1998 for the method.

Comment: Wow you're right!! My fault, I was using an HttpWebRequest with GetResponse() instead of GetResponseAsyn(). Thank you so much, I've learnt more about asynchronous methods and I got to understand why isn't necessary to mark the EventHandler as async :)

Comment: @LauraCP not to take anything away from Bruno's answer but I believe it would be good to mark this as the correct answer as we found the root cause for the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should run it in another task, so it won't freeze.

```
Task.Run(async () => {
        try
        {
            string decodedJson = await RestService.GetDataAsync(selectedCountry.name);
             Reply reply = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Reply>(decodedJsonInput);

      _replyCities = new ObservableCollection<City>(reply.Cities);
      picker2.ItemsSource = _replyCities;
      picker2.IsEnabled = true;


        }
        catch (System.OperationCanceledException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Text load cancelled: {ex.Message}");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    });
```

Comment: You could do this but I would rather then not mark the event handler async. Also most likely manipulating picker2 from a Task will result in exception as only the UI thread can modify the UI. 

You would have to wrap up the calls inside Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread method delegate.

Comment: I just had to wrap the lines `picker2.ItemsSource` and `picker2.ItemsSource` within `Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => {        });` as @SKall suggested and it worked fine! Thank you both

Comment: @LauraCP take a look at my solution as well. There is a reason why I didn't mark the event handler async... :)